# C# Character Escape Not Getting What's Expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After executing this C# line:

```
String x = "This is a \"Test\"";
```

I want x to equal this:

```
This is a "Test"
```

but instead it is this:

```
This is a \"Test\"
```

What am I doing wrong? No escapes sequences that I try work. I am doing this in Visual Studio so I was wondering whether there is some setting I changed inadvertently, or whether I am doing this wrong?

Comment: What about when you do `Console.WriteLine(x);`? What does it print?

Comment: Is that output line printed or in the debugger?

Comment: I'd bet significant amounts of money that you're looking at the string in the debugger which is "helpfully" escaping it for you. Print it on the console: the backslashes aren't there. Or look at the `Length` property, which will show you that it's 17, not 19.

Comment: You are storing them as a string. If you want it to be a string and reads: "This is a "Test". Concatenate them using single quotes. string x = "This is a " + '"' + "Test" + '"';

Comment: @jmag That's going to look the same in the debugger as what they are already doing.

Comment: No, it is not. I tested it.

Comment: Actually, I tested string x = "This is a " + '"' + "Test" + '"';  and string x = "This is a \"Test\""; Both resulted in "This is a "Test" so the given answer is correct.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with Jon Skeet's assertion that this is a duplicate question. The question he refers to is asking how to include the backslash in the string. This question asks how to NOT have it included. Before I asked this question, I looked at the one Jon refers to and did not recognize it as being relevant for that reason. I see now that the solution can be discerned from it since in both cases it was an IDE presentation issue. So while the answer is the same in both, the question is in fact different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `x` does contain the string that you want but the escape sequences might still be displayed in the IDE, depending on where you are looking at it (e.g., in the debugger). In an application, e.g., using `Console.WriteLine(x);` for output, the string will be displayed without the backslashes.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I figured the IDE was a factor. Good thing to know!

Comment: No, he was just trying to page me about a matter not related to this question.